# What would cause a unexpected token in typescript outputed map file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, tsconfig

I have a typescript project with a `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

I am running a script `"test:integration": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc && mocha test/integration/** --recursive"`

I then see:

```
/Users/mm81509/projects/coverpath-producer-management/test/integration /Example.js.map:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { {"version":3,"file":"Example.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["Example.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"","sourcesContent":[""]}
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
...
```

What would cause the typescript compiler make a syntax error in the map.js? I am only seeing this error in that one file in the project.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error on a `.map` file. These files are for mapping source lines to compiled lines. Adjust the glob pattern you pass to Mocha so that it does not try to load the `.map` files as test files. Something like:

```
mocha 'test/integration/**/*.js' --recursive
```

It will only load the `.js` files and not the `.map` files. And I suggest putting the single quotes to protect the pattern from being expanded by your shell. You want the pattern to be passed to Mocha as is instead of being interpreted by the shell.